# Why the response-content returned from Invoke-WebRequest is too short?

Tags: rest, api, powershell

I am trying to make a REST request to fetch some data from a server using `PowerShell`. The commandlet I am using is `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://server" -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" -Credential $cred
```

This request will run successfully with this result:

```
StatusCode       : 200
StatusDescription: OK
Content          : 25/08/2018 11:49:51   INFO   Start-Time ...
RawContent       : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
......
```

Actually I am fetching a log file and the file content should be returned in the HTTP body as content. However, the content returns only 2-3 line and the rest is omitted. How can I obtain the full content of the log file in the content section of the response body?

Comment: Try `Invoke-RestMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this to get JSON content from web services.  You can probably use something similar

```
$resp = Invoke-WebRequest ....
Write-Information -Message $resp.StatusCode
Write-Information -Message $resp.Content
$json = $resp.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

If you just want the content and can ignore all errors you can use:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest ...).Content
```

As noted elsewhere Invoke-RestMethod does some of this automagically  ... if you're calling a REST API.